# Why did Ralph get involved particularly with Tracee?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-sopranos

It is clear from more than one scene in [*The Sopranos* (1999-2007)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0141842/) that Ralph certainly does not respect the dancer/hooker Tracee and really does not like her much. If he is just using her, why does he spend so much time around her since it is not required that he do this to have access to her?

Was their relationship initially more mutual -- did Ralph actually like her at one point? She does not seem to be his type -- Ralph is not a nice guy but he is I think supposed to be one of the more intelligent gangsters and his becoming bored with her seems inevitable.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I mean, Ralph got her pregnant so it's safe to say that at SOME point her found her desirable enough.  Tracee had no contact with her family, which is usually indicative of abuse, as well as already having a son with no partner in the picture, so it's not hard to see that Tracee was craving attention and likely drawn to the power that Ralph had.  This explains why she doted on him while he mostly ignored her.  However, in order for all of that to happen, it had to have started with some form of mutual attraction.

Unfortunately, due to the fact that she only appeared in 2 episodes, her back story and her relationship with Ralph was never fully explored, so a lot has to be assumed.